# Update Attribute in Other Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have two tables/models (User and Holiday). A user has a set number of holidays. In the Holiday model, a user can book a number of holidays (integer).

Example: 
1) John has a total 10 holiday credit
2) John books 4 holidays

Result:  John has 6 holidays left

I know it has something to do with adding a method in User and passing the holidays taken into it.

How do I go about deducting the holidays booked from the holiday credit?

Comment: can you paste db structure for holiday model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the in User model:

```
# assuming, you have a method `holidays_booked`,
# that returns the number of booked holidays
def holidays_left
  10 - holidays_booked
end
```

That's it.

Comment: I understand the logic, however, `holidays_booked` is located in the Holiday Model. How do I go about accessing it? Furthermore, do I need to have a before_save or before_validation to calculate the holidays_left?

Answer (score 1):

If each user has a `holiday` property/field, then through associations between the two tables the value can be calculated.

When setting up the database a default value for the holiday credit can be defined. For example:

If you are adding a column to hold the value:

```
add_column :users, :holiday_credit, :integer, :default => 10
```

Now every user will have a default holiday credit in your database. This could also be done at object creation time during the object's initialization.

To update the value, a method within the User model can be written like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def calculate_holiday_credits
    self.holiday_credit = default_value - Holiday.find(self.id).count
  end
end
```

The function can be modified to accommodate your needs, but I hope this gives you the general idea.

In short, you want to search in the other table the number of times the id for the user model shows up and carry out your calculation with the results.

The booking mechanism would be sort of the inverse of this. In the holiday table, you want to make a method that creates an entry in the database with the user who booked the holiday, so that when the user runs the method detailed above, the value is update appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the code snippet above, however, there's no change on the credit value. I already have a method which creates the entry (thank goodness for scaffolding) in the holiday table. Additionally, shouldn't the `default_value` be replaced with `self.holiday_credit`?

Comment: Not good. 1) You are defining a method on the User class itself, not on the instance of the class. 2) you ABuse `self` - it should not have been used (in your snippet) only while assigning `holiday_credit`. 3) `Holiday.find(self.id).count` will not return anything, because `self.id` here is the id of the class (even if it would be the id of user instance - it still does not make sense). 4. you do not need parenthesis while defining a method in Ruby.

Comment: I have edited my response as Andrey was correct. As for your other question Jose, it is a matter of implementation. The evaluation can make use of the old self holiday value.